# Why do nodes have a maximum peer count?

Tags: network, nodes, peers, connection

Why do nodes have a maximum peer count, in other words what could go wrong if each node is connected to all the nodes of the network?

Answer (score 2):

Holding the state of a peer and handling its requests consumes resources. Mainly RAM, bandwidth and CPU. Each additional peer has a fixed cost for a node but a decreasing utility.

Comment: You could additionally mention that due to the limit on listening nodes there is also a limited amount of slots for other nodes to make inbound connections in the first place.

Comment: I initially started writing something along these lines but figured it didn't answer the question which was rather about why is there a limit at all for those listening nodes, if i'm understanding correctly. But i don't mind adding it.